# __call function in codeigniter library

Tags: codeigniter

I was just going through the curl library for codeigniter to understand the code. Here is the [link](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-curl). There is this function __call() which I am not sure about. Is it an inbuilt function in CI? I suppose it is called whenever any method of this library is called, for example using

```
$this->curl->simple_get();
```

Can someone please shed the light. I couldn't find much info on the codeigniter user guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - __call() is a php function. It is known as one of the magic methods.

The magic method `__call()` is to undeclared methods what `__get()` and `__set()` are to undeclared data member.

These methods are automatically called internally when the program tires to execute a method that has not been defined within the class at the time of development.

`__call()` takes two arguments. The first argument is the name of the undeclared method invoked by the program and the second is an array that contains a list of parameters passed to the undeclared array

- check http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Example

```
class Customer {

    public function __call($name, $args) {
        var_dump($name);
        echo "\n";
        var_dump($args);
        echo "\n";
    }
}

$c = new Customer();
$c->setName("some","name");
```

[Ref](http://www.sunilb.com/php/php5-oops-tutorial-magic-methods-__call-method)

Answer (score 0):

__call() is a magic function in OOP, it's invoked if the function isn't found. So because there is no simple_get() function inside the Curl class, the __call() function will be called, and you can see, there is a comment there, what will happen with the method call.